# Codeigniter css not found (htaccess issue)

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-2

I am using cPanel to host my codeigniter app. It is running fine on localhost. But when I uploaded it to server, it gave 404 error for all CSS files and hence it is showing the webpage  without any CSS included(all assets links broken).

I used the browser inspector to see that it was 404 errors(issued by server, not CodeIgniter).
Here is link for CSS:

`http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/~demo/assets/css/bootstrap.css //server 404 error`

Then I tried to access the CSS files by native method, i.e:

`http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/~demo/index.php?/assets/css/bootstrap.css //CodeIgniter 404 error`

which issued CodeIgniter's 404 error.

This looks like I am having some issue with the `htaccess`
Here is my `htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /~work2/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I am able to get the main page of the website, i.e default controller, but could not get other pages, like about us, etc.

I have tried other solutions but nothing seems working. Can anyone rectify the problem.
PS: I had tried installing cakePHP before it, end up having same issue with that too

Comment: try changing `RewriteBase /~work2/` to `RewriteBase/` only

Comment: it was already `RewriteBase/` but that didn't worked so I changed to this. It is sure that something like `mod_rewrite` is not enabled on the server, as same .htaccess is working on another cpanel. But I want to know if disabled `mod_rewrite` can cause this issue or not? Or maybe one can suggest possible explanations

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your .htaccess file so that it no longer rewrites requests made to '/assets'.

See this answer for the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27285645/508905

Answer (score 0):

In css folder create **.htaccess** file and write
**Allow from all**
then try