# codeigniter javascript not found error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I am sorry for my bad english, I am spanish and I am sorry if I have made something wrong, this is my first post.

I have a problem with loading a javascript file in codeigniter 2.1.4. I didn´t get loaded it in the header of my page. The css files were well loaded. This example attempts to load jquery and bootstrap.

I am following the steps in the documentation of codeigniter and when I create the codeigniter static page "home.php" I want to use bootstrap for design.

The tutorial I followed is this:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

My folder structure :

> - htdocs
>
>   - myproject (curriculos)
>
>     - application
>
>       - controller
>
>         - pages.php
>       - views
>
>         - templates
>
>           - header.php
>         - pages
>
>           - home.php
>           - about.php
>     - system
>     - assets
>
>       - bootstrap
>
>         - css
>
>           - bootstrap.min.css
>         - js
>
>           - bootstrap.min.js
>       - jquery- 2.1.0.min.js

I have been searching in this forum and others and always I find the same example with base_url() or site_url(). These are mine:

Updated code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My autoload.php with url helper loaded:

```
$ autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

When I try to load the page I get these errors:

```
GET http://localhost/curriculos/assets/jquery-2.1.0.min.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/curriculos/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/curriculos/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

The strangest is that when you click on one of them it shows you that the file type is trying to be loaded as a text/html and not as an application/javascript as usual:

[image: Error loading: file type text/html]

Can you help me?

Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: are the images working fine or the same is the problem with the images?

Comment: I uploaded a new image with new suggestions.Is this your question? Maybe I didn't understand you well.

Comment: Sorry for my english, now I think that I understand you. Yes, the image is correct for the new updated code. Sorry, my text editor teased me when I copied my question from the editor to stack overflow.

Comment: I found the problem. The problem is the .htaccess from codeigniter to hide index.php in url ¬¬. This is my .htaccess:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Someone knows how to change the .htaccess to admit .js files?

@Guns @Jai @shan22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your .htaccess file so that it no longer rewrites requests made to '/assets'.

In other words, you need your .htaccess file to ignore requests to the 'assets' folder and just let the browser load the url as provided. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script  src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This is the correct path.Try it!

Comment: Thank you shan22 but the problem is the codeigniter .htaccess :).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the .htaccess provided by codeigniter to remove the index.php. Follow this link:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/urls.html

Remove this code in your .htaccess and you can load javascript files :).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assets folder must be outside the application folder. Like below snapshot. Then user the below code in views files to include css, js and fonts files.

[Folder structure for css/js/fonts files in codeigniter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXZXS.png)

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/bootstrap.js"); ?>"></script>
```